What are the possible triangular sums?
Using all the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 each exactly once, place a number into each circle in the diagram below so that the sums of the numbers on each of the three sides of the triangle are equal to the same number.  Call this common sum S.
What are the possible values of S?

Attribution:  Gauss Contest Grade 7, 2018


 Let $T$ be the sum of the numbers at the triangle vertices. Then $1+2+3\le T\le 6+7+8$.
 $3S=1+2+\dots + 8 + T$ that is $S=12+T/3$ and so $14\le S\le 19$.


 Moreover, the case $S=14$ is impossible, because then the numbers $1$, $2$, and $3$ should be placed at the corners,
 but then it is easy to check that we cannot place the number $8$.


 The case $S=18$ is impossible too because then $T=18=S$, so the numbers at the top vertex and at the middle of the bottom side should be equal.


 The solutions for the remaining cases are:


 
     1         4         6          6
    3 8       1 3       1 4        2 1
   5   4     5   7     3   5      3   5
  6  7  2   6  8  2   7  8  2    8  4  7

  S = 15    S = 16    S = 17     S = 19
 



 Partial answer, starting clockwise from the top: 6,3,2,8,4,7,5,1 gives side sum of 19. I couldn’t prove that this is the only sum.


Good start!  Keep going.
